# Pasar los checkbox de un formulario a un php con date and time picker

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-datepicker

Deseo pasar unos valores de varios checkbox de un formulario y visualizarnos en otro archivo php. Tengo 3 opciones:

- Pase de Entrada
- Pase de Salida
- Falta

Cuando seleccionan Pase de Entrada y Pase de salida tengo dos variables `chk[]` que me permiten capturar los valores seleccionados, cada opción tiene un datepicker (`date[]`) y timepicker (`time[]`) a excepcion de Falta, que tiene solo un datepicker(`date[]`).

Lo que deseo es que cuando seleccione un `date[]` en la variable time el valor sea "Todo el día" pues si una persona falta a trabajar se entiende que solo debe seleccionar una fecha y la hora será pues en todo el día.

El problema es que cuando pongo en el value="Todo el día", si yo selecciono Pase de Entrada o Pase de Salida, al final de la linea me aparece "Todo el día"

¿Hay modo de que esto no salga? Si yo selecciono pase de entrada o salida pues claro debo seleccionar hora y fecha con date and time picker, pero si yo selecciono Falta que solo me elija Date Picker sin que me ponga Falta todo el día en las otras dos opciones.

Anexo el código y una captura de pantalla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
</div>
<label class="col-sm-2">Tipo de Pase</label>
<div class="col-sm-3">
<div class="form-check"><label class="form-check-label"><input class="form-check-input" id="pase_de_entrada" type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="Pase de entrada" onchange="javascript:showContent()" /> Pase de Entrada </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check"><label class="form-check-label"><input class="form-check-input" id="pase_de_salida" type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="Pase de salida" onchange="javascript:showContent1()" /> Pase de Salida </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check"><label class="form-check-label"><input class="form-check-input" id="falta_dia" type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="Falta todo el dia" onchange="javascript:showContent2()" /> Falta <!---->
</label>
</div>

<div id="content2" style="display: none;">
<div class="form-group row" id="div3">
<label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2 col-form-label" for="fecha_justificar">Fecha a Justificar Falta</label>
<div class="col-md-4"><input class="form-control" id="date3" name="date[]" placeholder="MM/DD/YYY" type="text" value=""/></div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquerys/datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquerys/datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var date_input=$('input[name="date[]"]'); //our date input has the name "date"
var container=$('.bootstrap-iso form').length>0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
var options={
format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
container: container,
todayHighlight: true,
autoclose: true,
};
date_input.datepicker(options);
})
</script>
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="time[]" id="time3" value="Todo el dia">
<!--Si yo coloco en value ="Todo el dia" me aparece el valor aun no seleccionando el check "Falta"-->

</div>
</div>
```

y aqui el PHP

```
echo "<h1> Vista previa de los datos </h1>";
if (isset($_GET['enviar'])) {
    if (is_array($_GET['chk'])) {
        $selected = '';
        $num_datos = count($_GET['chk']);
        $current = 0;
        foreach ($_GET['chk'] as $key => $value) {
            if ($current != $num_datos-1)
                $selected .= $value.'   ';
            else
                $selected .= $value.'   ';
            $current++;
        }
    }
    else {
        $selected = 'Debes seleccionar una opcion';
    }

    echo '<div>Tipo de Pase seleccionado : '.$selected.'</div>';
}    

if (isset($_GET['enviar'])) {
    if (is_array($_GET['date'])) {
        $selected1 = '';
        $num_datos1 = count($_GET['date']);
        $current1 = 0;
        foreach ($_GET['date'] as $key1 => $value1) {
            if ($current1 != $num_datos1-1)
                $selected1 .= $value1.'   ';
            else
                $selected1 .= $value1.'   ';
            $current1++;
        }
    }
    else {
        $selected1 = 'Debes seleccionar una opcion';
    }

    echo '<div>Fecha Solicitada: '.$selected1.'</div>';
}    


if (isset($_GET['enviar'])) {
    if (is_array($_GET['time'])) {
        $selected2 = '';
        $num_datos2 = count($_GET['time']);
        $current2 = 0;
        foreach ($_GET['time'] as $key2 => $value2) {
            if ($current2 != $num_datos2-1)
                $selected2 .= $value2.'   ';
            else
                $selected2 .= $value2.'   ';
            $current2++;
        }
    }
    else {
        $selected2 = 'Debes seleccionar una opcion';
    }

    echo '<div>Horario Solicitado: '.$selected2.'</div>';
}    

$fecha_de_solicitud=$_GET['fecha_de_solicitud'];

echo ' La fecha del alta del justificante es ' .$fecha_de_solicitud.''; 
echo '<br>';

?>
```

Comment: Una gran disculpa a todos, la verdad es que soy novato en el uso de este tipo de foros y ayudas y no supe que hacer o como acomodar. Con experiencia iré solucionando estos inconvenientes.

Comment: Aqui esta el codigo en Bitbucket para ser editable https://juanelobus@bitbucket.org/juanelobus/codigos-con-dudas-jpbl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bueno la solucion a tu problema es simple, primero que nada, quita el input hidden con el value="Todo el día".
Luego Para identificar que has seleccionado "Falta", cambia el nombre del checkbox de "Falta" y ponle algo como name="chkFalta"

```
<div class="form-check"><label class="form-check-label"><input class="form-check-input" id="falta_dia" type="checkbox" name="falta" value="Falta todo el dia" onchange="javascript:showContent2()" /> Falta </label></div>
```

En el php debes colocar una condicion para que sepas que el input "chkFalta" fue marcado y asi indicar que faltará todo el día.. en el php quedaría así.

```
if (isset($_GET['enviar'])) {
    if(isset($_GET['falta'])){
        $selected2 = "Falta todo el día";
    }elseif (is_array($_GET['time'])) {
        $selected2 = '';
        $num_datos2 = count($_GET['time']);
        $current2 = 0;
        foreach ($_GET['time'] as $key2 => $value2) {
            if ($current2 != $num_datos2-1)
                $selected2 .= $value2.'   ';
            else
                $selected2 .= $value2.'   ';
            $current2++;
        }
    }
    else {
        $selected2 = 'Debes seleccionar una opcion';
    }

    echo '<div>Horario Solicitado: '.$selected2.'</div>';
}
```

Espero te sirva, saludos.

EDITO

---

Si, agrego el if para el chk del tipo de pase.

```
if (isset($_GET['enviar'])) 
{
    if(isset($_GET['chkfalta'])){
     $selected = 'Falta'; 
    }elseif (is_array($_GET['chk'])) {
        $selected = '';
        $num_datos = count($_GET['chk']);
        $current = 0;
        foreach ($_GET['chk'] as $key => $value) 
        {
            if ($current != $num_datos-1)
                $selected .= $value.'   ';
            else
                $selected .= $value.'   ';
            $current++;
        }
    }else{
                $selected = 'Debes seleccionar una opcion'; 
   }    

    echo '<div>Tipo de Pase seleccionado : '.$selected.'</div>';
}
```

Comment: De antemano muchisimas gracias por tu apoyo y comentario, ya me permite validar tanto si seleccion un pase de entrada y un pase de salida y me muestra la informacion. Asi como la Falta si yo la selecciono me sale en "Horario Solicitado: Falta todo el día"; pero ahora en "Tipo de Pase seleccionado" me aparece :Debes seleccionar una opcion"

Comment: En el if donde pone "Tipo de pase"  al else puedes colocar: 
    if(!isset($_GET['falta'])){
        $selected = 'Debes seleccionar una opcion';
    }

Comment: ¿Algo como esto?

Comment: if (isset($_GET['enviar'])){
    if (is_array($_GET['chk'])){
        $selected = '';
        $num_datos = count($_GET['chk']);
        $current = 0;
        foreach ($_GET['chk'] as $key => $value){
            if ($current != $num_datos-1)
                $selected .= $value.'   ';
            else
                $selected .= $value.'   ';
            $current++;}
    }else if(!isset($_GET['chkfalta'])){$selected = 'Debes seleccionar una opcion';} 
    echo '<div>Tipo de Pase seleccionado : '.$selected.'</div>';}

Comment: Exacto, ¿Ya funciona?

Comment: Negativo. Cuando selecciono tipo de Pase: Falta no me aparece Tipo de Pase Seleccionado: Falta.

Comment: Mira este es mi repositorio https://juanelobus@bitbucket.org/juanelobus/codigos-con-dudas-jpbl

Comment: Descargue el repo, lo subi a mi server y aparentemente me funciona.

Comment: Tipo de Pase seleccionado : Falta todo el dia
Fecha Solicitada: 12/12/2016
Horario Solicitado: Todo el dia
La fecha del alta del justificante es 13/09/2016

Comment: Vista previa de los datos

Tipo de Pase seleccionado : Pase de entrada
Fecha Solicitada: 13/09/2016
Horario Solicitado: 13:05
La fecha del alta del justificante es 13/09/2016

Comment: borrare el cache y las cookies de mi navegador puede que sea eso. Hare Pruebas y te informo. Gracias.

Comment: Okok listo! :D de nada amigo

Comment: Me aparece esto mira

Comment: Tipo de Pase seleccionado :
Fecha Solicitada: 14/09/2016
Horario Solicitado: Falta todo el día
La fecha del alta del justificante es 14/09/2016

Comment: Es decir en Tipo de Pase Seleccionado deberia aparecer "Falta todo el dia" sin embargo me lo deja en blanco.

Comment: http://veflat.com/Jhoubert/test/Index.php

Comment: Ya vi el problema, edite la respuesta, revisalo ! :)

Comment: Super bien! Ya vi mi error! La verdad es que ya con esto quedo :) No se como agradecerte. El detalle estaba en la condicion que coloque mal

Comment: ¿En donde te puedo calificar? Te agradezco demasiado el tiempo por haberme ayudado. Gracias infinitas.

Comment: De nada! espero tambien puedas haber aprendido un poco más, con mi ayuida, saludos..